# How do I auto restart a .sh script every few hours? (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: ubuntu

Hi I have a fiveM server running from a run.sh file however I am unsure on how to make the run.sh close and start again every few hours (aka the fiveM server restarts). Anyone know how I would do that?

Comment: maybe cron may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You should schedule your .sh script using the contrab

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800